# DispatcherTimer frozen while running through remote desktop

Tags: wpf, remote-desktop

I have an issue while running a WPF application on a remote machine and accessing it via remote desktop. The application seemed partially frozen: some bindings worked, some not. We only had this issue with a remote desktop connection, and after a few connections/disconnections.

My application should be relatively responsive and our users wanted to be sure that the application was not frozen even without interacting directly with it (it's kind of a monitoring application). 
To achieve that we've just added a simple clock on the main window that ticks every second.

The clock is updated every 250 ms by a `DispatcherTimer` setup with a priority at DataBinding level. We simply update a string bound to the UI at every timer's tick.

When the application is "frozen" (ie. the clock doesn't tick) I can attach my Visual Studio debugger and see that the timer is not enabled anymore and doesn't tick.

Here's some code :

**MainWindow** (our main UI) - *Code behind*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow** - *Xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="RdpDispatcherTimer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40pt" Text="{Binding Clock}"/>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel** used as the `DataContext` as you can see on the MainWindow's code behind

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _clock;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.DataBind) { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), IsEnabled = true };
        timer.Tick += (o, e) => Clock = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
    }

    public string Clock
    {
        get { return _clock; }
        set
        {
            _clock = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Clock)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Does anyone know what could cause the dispatcher timer to be disabled when connecting via remote desktop?

Comment: You don't need to use a DispatcherTimer for this.  Just run it on a background thread.  Bindings automatically marshal updates from INPC properties onto the UI thread.  Also, you might want to increase the time between updates.  Maybe every 900ms.  Reduce the pressure on the UI thread.  I'm not familiar with how RDP mucks with WPF applications, but those are the changes I'd make in trying to fix this.